# Vector subderivatives and "simple algebra" which turn out not to be so simple

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, numerical-optimization

In [Friedman, Hastie and Simon (2013)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6529.pdf) an algorithm is proposed for a group-LASSO penalized regression possibly involving many variables. The problem is as follows:

$\underset{\beta}{min}\{ \frac{1}{2}|| Y - X \beta ||_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{k \leq p} ||\beta_{k.}||_2\}$

with $Y$, an $n \times M$ matrix, $X$, an $n \times p$ matrix and $||a||_2^2 := \sqrt{a^Ta} $. Let use also note $X_{.k}$ as the $k^{th}$ column of a matrix $X$ and, $X_{k.}$ as its $k^{th}$ row.

They propose to take as given all $\beta_{j.}$ for $j \neq k$, except $\beta_{k.}$, hence we get the objective:

$\underset{\beta}{min}\{ \frac{1}{2}|| R_{-k} - X_{.k} \beta_{k.} ||_2^2 + \lambda ||\beta_{k.}||_2\}$

where $R_{-k} := Y - \sum_{j \neq k} X_{.j}\beta_{j.}$. From here, we can take a subderivative with respect to $\beta_{j.}$ so that our solution $\hat{\beta}_{k.}$ satisfies:

$- X_{.k}^TR_{-k} + ||X_{.k}||_2^2 \hat{\beta}_{k.} + \lambda S(\hat{\beta}_{k.}) = 0$

where $S(a) \begin{cases} = \frac{a}{||a||_2} \text{ } if a \neq 0 \\ \in \{u \; \; \text{s.t.} \; \; ||u||_2 \leq 1 \}
\end{cases}$

**Now, I have a questions.**
It concerns how you go from the FOC-like equation above to this equation:

$\hat{\beta}_{k.} = \frac{1}{||X_{.k}||_2^2} max\{0, 1 - \frac{\lambda}{||X_{.k}^T R_{-k}||_2} \} X_{.k}^T R_{-k}$

i.e., how do you isolate the solution vector in the FOC-like equation involving the subderivative? On page 4, they call it "simple algebra."

It's important that I understand it because I need to apply the same algorithm in a slightly different context. Instead of having a penalty of the form

$\lambda ||\beta_{k.}||_2$

I have one of the form

$\lambda ||W_{k.}||_2$

where $W := Q_n \beta$. If it is of any interest, I am an economist. I know some mathematics, but I am not a mathematician by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the missing algebra.

Given the FOC in terms of the row vector $a^T$
$$\eqalign{
(x^Tx)a^T + \Big(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{a^Ta}}\Big) a^T = x^TR \\
\Bigg(x^Tx + \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{a^Ta}}\Bigg) a^T = r^T \\
\Bigg(\chi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{\alpha}\Bigg) a^T = r^T \\
}$$
So $a$ is seen to be a scalar multiple of $r$.

Square both sides and solve for the unknown scalar $\alpha$.
$$\eqalign{
\Bigg(\chi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{\alpha}\Bigg)^2 \alpha^2 = \rho^2 \\
\Big(\alpha\chi^2 + \lambda\Big)^2 = \rho^2 \\
\alpha = \frac{\rho-\lambda}{\chi^2} \\
}$$
Substituting $\alpha$ recovers the $a$ vector in terms of the known quantities.

To relate this all to the current problem let
$$\eqalign{
a^T &= {\hat\beta},\quad &x = X_k,\quad &r^T = X_k^TR_k \\
\alpha^2 &= \|a\|^2,\quad &\chi^2 = \|x\|^2 ,\quad &\rho^2 = \|r\|^2 \\
}$$